# mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
> given in D:\Hosting\9864230\html\includes\connection.php on line 11

Database selection failed:

```
<?php
require "constants.php";

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
```

Comment: You have the wrong parameter order, set `$connection` before `DB_NAME` at your call to `mysqli_select_db()`. I don't think this question shows any search effort at all, try google or look at php.net next time.

Comment: Please learn about functions first before you use them, that includes learning about the meaning of each parameter as well as learning about the return value and the type of error handling that is used with the function.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808332/should-we-ever-check-for-mysqli-connect-errors-manually

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your arguments are in the wrong order. The connection comes first according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

```
<?php
require "constants.php";

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
```

You got the order of the arguments to `mysqli_select_db()` backwards.

Note also that with mysqli you can specify the DB in `mysqli_connect()`:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```